# correção da tag xWindow foi escrita como xWindows

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags

Ao escrever a pergunta [X-Window exibindo telas no Browser, Qual biblioteca é preciso para desenvolver este tipo de interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161182/x-window-exibindo-telas-no-browser-qual-biblioteca-%C3%A9-preciso-para-desenvolver-e), e registrar algumas tags me enganei e escrevi XWindows no plural, e deveria ser XWindow (ou X-Window), fui alertado do erro, mas a correção não está ao meu alcance.

Tentei usar no singular, mas o sistema me alerta da existência de uma versão no plural.

Por gentileza, corrijam se possível tal erro.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Está resolvido. Renomeei para o correto.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown